# Angular 2/Property Binding - Why does changing a property from component does not update the template correctly?

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection, property-binding

I have been coding in Angular for 8 months now and this is something strange that i ran into.

Basically, i am calling a function and passing it an ID. If that ID matches the data array, it should filter that entry out. Nothing odd there. But when i decrease the count of a variable/property binded to the template, it just becomes zero.

```
<ng-template #providerDetailHeader *ngIf="loggedInUserRole != 4">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-7">
    <div class="counts-div">
      <div class="open-count">
        <div *ngIf="openCount == 0">
          <h3>{{ openCount }}</h3>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="openCount > 0">
          <h3
            class="counter"
            [CountTo]="openCount"
            [from]="0"
            [duration]="1"
          ></h3>
        </div>
        <label>Open</label>
      </div>
        .
        .
        .
</ng-template>
```

Here is the function i am calling onClick of a button from frontend.
Function:

```
completeQueryItem(itemGuid: string): void { 
   this.data = this.data.filter((queryItem) => { 
      console.log('queryItem', queryItem); 
      return queryItem.itemGuid != itemGuid; 
   });
   this.openCount = this.openCount - 1; 
}
```

Note: I have also tried to debug the code but i couldn't find the exact place where this property becomes zero. I know it has something to do with change detection of angular. Please help me solve this. Thanks

Comment: The complete function code, sorry for not posting correctly

   

completeQueryItem(itemGuid: string): void {

    this.data = this.data.filter((queryItem) => {
                console.log('queryItem', queryItem);
                return queryItem.itemGuid != itemGuid;
              });

    this.openCount = this.openCount - 1;
}

Comment: is the component uses onPush strategy?

Comment: @RazRonen Nope.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the full code of `completeQueryItem`?

Comment: @ConnorsFan Done.

Comment: can you check in the `@Component({})` do you have `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`?

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan I do not have it there

Comment: @UsmanMajied if possible can you reproduce your issue on the stackblitz example and share with us the link. it will be helpful.

Comment: @UsmanMajied , the question is a bit unclear with details missing. Can you please create a minimum example in this project I created on StackBlitz:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fn4pzf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Here is the link. Although it is working as expected as can be seen from this StackBlitz example [stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zv7nnt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html]. I figured out what was causing the issue. 

I added 'angular-count-to' in my project for animating numbers but after commenting it out,  my code is working as expected.

 <div *ngIf="openCount > 0">
          <h3
            class="counter"
            [CountTo]="openCount"
            [from]="0"
            [duration]="1"
          ></h3>
        </div>

Comment: @UsmanMajied you need to fork the project and do the changes there. the link is the same as faisal example

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan I am sorry to reply late but i have the issue causing the properties not to update. It was the 'angular-count-to' library i had imported as seen in my template code. Thanks